# Create not exportable private key inside iOS keychain

Tags: ios, swift, security, rsa, keychain

I want to create an RSA private key which is not exportable (even by the developer of app) inside iOS keychain.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What would be the point of that? If your app can't access the private key then it can't use it for anything

Comment: @Paulw11: 'not exportable' doesn't mean 'not accessible'. For example Android has something called the [Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) from which private keys cannot be exported. Private key operations take place inside a hardware-protected environment.

Comment: @Paulw11 as PresidentJamesK.Polk said in the case that I want, we can use the private key but we can't read it directly. In iOS there is Secure Enclave that provides such that thing but unfortunately it only supports EC keys.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible with RSA.

You *can* create keys which can't be exported, but [only in the Secure Enclave](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/protecting_keys_with_the_secure_enclave), and it only supports p256 key pairs. You can't import existing keys into the Secure Enclave. While it is possible to export a key from it, the key is encrypted such that only that exact Secure Enclave can import it again later.

Comment: Yes I know about Secure Enclave but as you mentioned it only supports EC keys. So it seems that I can't fix my problem with RSA key. Thanks.